# CSS3 Transitions: replace them entirely on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a responsive web site and would like to use this effect for desktop versions only (where the screen is big enough).

The code looks like this:

```
        <div class="block_holder">
            <div class="hover_block block_4">
                <img src="images/thumbnail.png" />
                <div class="top_half">Top Div that slides down on hover</div>
                <div class="bottom_half">Bottom Div that slides up on hover</div> 
                <div class="hover_info">Caption text content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Transitions take place in these classes: .block_4 .top_half .block_4 .bottom_half and all content in .hover_info to produce the hover effect.

For mobile, I would just like the photo to just be clickable, without any transitions since there is no hover. Is there a way to replace the entire block of code with something like this:

```
            <p>
                <a id="fancybox-manual-b" href="javascript:;" class="link"><img src="images/patterns_thumb.png" alt="pattern" class="portfolio"/></a>
                Patterns made in Adobe Illustrator
            </p>
```

I've tried setting .top_half .bottom_half and .hover_info to "display: none;" in the @media section designated for mobile and tablet and then making the img a link, but the image is not clickable using the first code provided. Why is this?

I apologize if there is an obvious solution for this, I have not found or thought of any.

Comment: `href="javascript:;"` doesn't do anything. What are you trying to link to?

Comment: In my code when that link is clicked it runs a script associated with the ID.

Comment: Try removing href and placing onclick in your <a> tag and instead of javascript: , call some function.

Comment: These codes work fine separately, but my problem is implementing one or the other depending on @media screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off using modernizer for this.

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {
    $('.top_half,.bottom_half,.hover_info').hide();
    $('.hover_block img').click(function() {
         alert('I was clicked');
    }).css('cursor','pointer');
}
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/LHLHG/